# Facebook real time update - "inbox" is an invalid field name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer I am posting this:

```
appID/subscriptions?access_token=appID|appToken&object=user&fields=about,quotes,inbox&callback_url=http://example.com/callback.php&verify_token=tok
```

But I am getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": (#100) "inbox" is an invalid field name,
    "type": OAuthException,
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

What is wrong with field inbox? On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ there is this field.

I am trying to set it up so Facebook should let me know in realtime when user obtains new message in his inbox.

EDIT: "Inbox" is NOT FIELD but EDGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inbox` is not a field name, it´s an API endpoint. Make sure you understand the difference. And as you can read in the docs about the [Realtime API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/), there is no subscription field called `inbox`.

Comment: btw I tried to search docs for best implementation to get notification about new message but did not find it. Do you know to point me right way?

Comment: i don´t think it´s possible with the realtime api. how to read the inbox is explained in the docs though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/inbox